# How to convert to use the Yii CDataProvider on view?

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to learn Yii, and have looked at Yii documentation, but still do not really get it. I still have no idea how to use the CDataProvider on the Controller and View to display all the blog posts available on the view. Can anyone please advise or give an example based on the following:

The actionIndex in my PostController:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $posts = Post::model()->findAll();

    $this->render('index', array('posts' => $posts));
));
```

The View, Index.php:

```
<div>
<?php foreach ($post as $post): ?>
<h2><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h2>
<?php echo CHtml::decode($post['content']); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Instead of doing the above, can anyone please advise how to use the CDataProvider to generate instead?

Many thanks.

Comment: i saw this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView but 1) how to echo the data? 2) and is it possible to have it shown on the index instead of creating another _post, as seen in the 'itemView'=>'_post'?

Comment: oh i posted an answer without reading this comment! Can you tell me why do you want to echo the data directly? It is obviously possible, will add some code to my answer, shortly.

Comment: Answer edited, ok you want with clistview, but without itemView, thats not possible, thats not how CListView works. It is highly customizable, trust me, the whole look can be changed drastically!

Comment: Incase you didn't know, CDataProvider is the abstract base class for the other data providers in yii, namely, CActiveDataProvider, CArrayDataProvider, and CSqlDataProvider.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Can I say that, because of the itemView, it is much like having the _view acting like a little component, and you just have to plug this component (like the php include) into the index page to output the results, and customize the individual _view without having to affect any other parts of the index page?

Comment: Is it flexible to also add another element into a single page, e.g. post view page where the contents could be loaded through the CDetailView, and also an add comment form within the same post view page?

Comment: You are correct about the _view, be careful though about the data you have to pass, and remember it's only for clistview, afaik. There might be extensions that implement a similar technique. And yes you can add as many components as you want, again just be sure about what data is needed by the component.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best that i can suggest is using a [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView) in your view, and a [CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) in your controller. So your code becomes somewhat like this :

**Controller**:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Post');

    $this->render('index', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider));
}
```

**index.php**:

```
<?php
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  'itemView'=>'_post',   // refers to the partial view named '_post'
  // 'enablePagination'=>true   
   )
  );
?>
```

**_post.php**: this file will display each post, and is passed as an attribute of the widget CListView(*namely* `'itemView'=>'_post'`) in your index.php view.

```
 <div class="post_title">
 <?php 
 // echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('title'));
 echo CHtml::encode($data->title);
 ?>
 </div>

 <br/><hr/>

 <div class="post_content">
 <?php 
 // echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('content'));
 echo CHtml::encode($data->content);
 ?>
 </div>
```

#### Explanation

Basically in the index action of the controller we are creating a new CActiveDataProvider, that *provides* data of the Post model for our use, and we pass this dataprovider to the index view.
In the index view we use a **Zii** widget CListView, which uses the dataProvider we passed as data to generate a list. Each data item will be rendered as coded in the itemView file we pass as an attribute to the widget. This itemView file will have access to an object of the Post model, in the $data variable.

Suggested Reading: Agile Web Application Development with Yii 1.1 and PHP 5

A very good book for Yii beginners, is listed in the Yii homepage.

#### Edit:

As asked without CListView

index.php

```
<?php
 $dataArray = $dataProvider->getData();
foreach ($dataArray as $data){
echo CHtml::encode($data->title);
echo CHtml::encode($data->content);
}
?>
```

Comment: leave comment, for clarifications/discussion

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation. now i have a clearer picture about echoing the result with and without the use of the Listview, with the data from the dataProvider.

Comment: in case of without clistview, how can we provide pagination links?

Comment: @ASD have you tried the [CPagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination) class?

Comment: @bool.dev Yes i got it. One more clarification, can we use this pagination links with jquerymobile dynamically creating list? (using ajax call)

Comment: i'm sorry i haven't tried with jquery mobile yet, so i can't say for sure, but i think it should work. btw, if you think my answer(not comment) helped please upvote it.

Comment: @bool.dev Actually yes it helped me and i upvoted it :) In case if you try jquerymobile dynamic list with pagination, please let me know. :) thanks in adv.

Comment: @ASD ok, are you using dataprovider also?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12271/discussion-between-asd-and-bool-dev)