# yii how to use CListView

Tags: php, yii

I have the following code and it works but I want to convert this to list view. How can I do this.

```
foreach ($jobs as $job){
     $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
        'data'=>$job,
        'attributes'=>array(
            'JOBNO',
            'PROJID',
            'NAME',
            'SEQ',
            'DATEIN',
            'DATEDONE',
            'STATUS',
            'PCENTDONE',
            'EARNED',
            'VALUE',
            'COMMENTS',
            'SENTBACK',
            'DATEDUE',
            'ORIGTAPES',
            'Timestamp',
        ),
    ));

    echo "<hr />";
}
```

Comment: apart from reading the documentation, you might want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9228963/720508)

Comment: Site like this exists because the documentation is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a data provider with you model:

```
//in your controller
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
//your criterias to get your data

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('MODELNAME',
                array(
                        'criteria'  => $criteria,
                )
            );

//in your view
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'itemView'=>'_view',
));
```

Comment: Usign that code I received this "The property "itemView" cannot be empty. "

Comment: I think is necessary to give the name of the partial view in the itemView property

Answer (score 3):

Access this url:

[Yii official refference class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/)

Now, type: `clistview`

Wait ... and now select the first result;

It will take you here:

[clistview refference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView)

and on that page , you will see:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post');

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_post',   // refers to the partial view named '_post'
    'sortableAttributes'=>array(
        'title',
        'create_time'=>'Post Time',
    ),
));
```

Comment: clistview is completely different from gridview. i want gridview without the searchable part.